# daterange picker issue: rp.find('.range-end').datepicker('getDate') returns null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, daterangepicker

**SCENARIO**

A very simply daterangepicker instance:

```
<div class="section">
    <label for="drp">date-range-picker</label>
    <input type="text" id="drp" />
    <script>
        (function(){
            $('#drp').daterangepicker({
                presetRanges: [
                        { text: 'Last 30 days',
                            dateStart: function () { return Date.parse('today').add({day: -30}) },
                            dateEnd: function () { return Date.parse('today').add({day: -1}); }
                        },
                        { text: 'Previous month'
                            , dateStart: function () { return Date.today().add({month:-1}).moveToFirstDayOfMonth()}
                            , dateEnd: function () { return Date.today().add({month:-1}).moveToLastDayOfMonth(); }
                        },
                        { text: 'Current month'
                            , dateStart: function () { return Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth()}
                            , dateEnd: function () { return Date.today().add({day:-1}); }
                        }
                    ],
                presets: {dateRange: 'Select range'},
                rangeStartTitle: 'Start date', rangeEndTitle: 'End date', doneButtonText: 'Done', prevLinkText: 'Prev', nextLinkText: 'Next',
                rangeSplitter: ' - ', dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", closeOnSelect: true
            });
        })();
    </script>
</div>
```

The includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript" src="client/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript" src="client/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.jQuery.js"></script>
```

**Question**

In local env everything works right. In the production enviroment the following error occurs after selecting any preset:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDate' of null @daterangepicker.jQuery.js:162
```

The error raises because when the next statements are executed:

var range_end = rp.find('.range-end');
[...]
var rangeB = fDate( range_end.datepicker('getDate') );

I am getting mad. It seems that the daterangepicker does not initialize the datepicker in the `.range-end` class element. But I cannot figure out what is wrong.

No others error in the (Chrome) console.

**References**

- https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide js fiddle. Actually I am not able to add a comment to your question so I have to write this as an answer.